# Example of Taylor series converging to wrong function that isn't the $e^{-1/x}$ example

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, taylor-expansion

It's a well-known result that the Taylor series of a function can converge but to the wrong function, and the common example is for the function at the origin.

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      e^{-1/x} & x \gt 0
   \end{cases} $$

This is simply because the function is infinitely differentiable at the origin, but all derivatices are $0$, therefore the Taylor series converges to the (trivial) zero function which is obviously not equal to $f(x)$.

I would like another example of this 'convergent to wrong funciton' property, but with a messier example. (Ideally I'd like to be able to draw two non-trivial graphs, one of the correct function and one of the incorrect Taylor function)

Comment: See what happens with $f(x)=\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t} }}{{1 + tx^2 }}dt}$.

Comment: Note that the function $e^{-x}$ is already not analytic at $0$. Using the central differential ( you know $(f (h) - f(-h)) / 2h$ ) already shows this without involving complex numbers. It is already not continu nor differentiable at 0. So clearly you had to differentiate the 0 function and  thus end up at all zero derivatives.
You might want to look into nowhere analytic C^oo functions and fourier series.
Equal to its taylor series and analytic are equivalent if the radius of the taylor series is nonzero.

Comment: take exp(x) at x = - oo. all the derivatives there are 0 !!

Answer (score 2):

I am no sure whether you think or not that what I write below is an answer. If you think that it is not, say so, and I shall delete it.

If you are after an example which doesn't involve a function $f$ such that $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z_+):f^{(n)}(0)=0$, you shall not find one. In fact, let $f$ be a $C^\infty$ function such that its Taylor series converges to some function $g$ such that, for some $\varepsilon>0$,$$\bigl(\forall x\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\setminus\{0\}\bigr):f(x)\ne g(x)$$and let $h=f-g$. Then, for each $n\in\Bbb Z_+$,$$h^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(0)-g^{(n)}(0)=n!\left(\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}-\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Oh, are you saying the *only* exampes of Taylor series converging to the 'wrong function' is in these 'trivial' cases of it converging to the zero function?

Comment: Not exactly. They can be small variations of that one, such as when you take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\leqslant0\\x+e^{-1/x}&\text{ if }x>0.\end{cases}$$But, in the end, the same sort of phenomenon will take place.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks!

Comment: Can these flat functions only occur in the real analytic case, not the complex case?

Comment: They cannot even occur in the real analytic case. They can only occur in the case of $C^\infty$ *non*-analytic functions. If $f$ is analytic and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z_+$, then $f(x)=0$ in some neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the Taylor series $\sum a_n x^n$ of the function $f(x)$ has non-trivial radius of convergence,

the function $(f(x)-\sum a_n x^n)$ has Taylor series zero.

Therefore, you're basically asking for all functions that have Taylor series zero.

There's a Wikipedia page for those functions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function

Comment: Can these flat functions only occur in the real analytic case, not the complex case?

Comment: Not in the complex case. Complex function differentiable on an open set $\implies$ function equal to its Taylor series. @AlexGower